# Concurrent triples of chords in a regular n-gon

Tags: geometry, polygons

[image]

$\textit{Fig. 1 : Quadrilateral $ABCD$ of the Langleys 80-80-20 problem}$$\textit{inside a regular polygon with 36 vertices}$$\textit{This figure is just an introduction ; proceed now to Fig. 2}.$

A now classical question (the $80-80-20$ problem, as mentionned in the second figure [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%27s_Adventitious_Angles), is frequently posted on this site, for example some days ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4587485).

Although I know that this type of question is solved by angle chasing (with construction of auxiliary points or lines), I have attempted to see if this issue can be settled in the framework of diagonals belonging to a certain regular $n$-gon. As the GCD of all angles is $10°$, I chose $n=36$, and made use of the theorem of the inscribed angle (in particular the fact that the center angle is twice the inscribed angle sustending a same arc). I arrived in this way at figure $1$.
The purpose was, I would say, recreational, because it couldn't achieve a better solution (with the added fact that line segment $CD$ isn't part of a diagonal of the $36$-gon).

**But**, working on figure $1$, I discovered a property which is summarized in figure $2$ :

$$\text{The 3 (orange) chords } \  AG, \ BH ,\ EI \ \ \text{are concurrent}\tag{1}$$

and
$$\text{The 3 (blue) chords } \  AJ, \ BJ, \ EK \ \ \text{are concurrent.}\tag{2}$$

[image]

$\textit{Fig. 2 : With the same points as in figure 1}$ $\textit{highlighting the intersecting chords triples (orange) (1) and (blue) (2).}$

Please note that figure 2 is the same as figure 1, but "installed" into a certain coordinate system : the polygon has unit radius and point $A$ has coordinates $(1,0)$ (the idea behind that : allowing the representation of each vertex of the polygon by a $36$-th root of unity $\omega^k$ where $\omega= e^{i \pi/18}$).

**Question 1 :** How to prove (1) and (2) in a rigorous way ?

Till now, I have only be able to check (1) and (2) in a numerical way. In particular, my attempts with $n$-th roots of unity haven't been successful.

**Question 2 :** Beyond question 1, are there other concurrent chords triples in a regular convex $36$-gon (of course different from those obtained by simple rotation...) ? More generally, what can be said about such concurrent triples for a general regular convex $n$-gon ?

---

**Edit** : answer to question 1, which amounts to prove the answer given by Blue.

Let us consider 3 diagonals

$$[M_p,M_q], \ \ [M_r,M_s], \ \ [M_u,M_v], \ \ $$

with the conventional notation $M_k=(\cos(ka),\sin(ka))$ where $a=\tfrac{2 \pi}{k}$.

The resp. equations of the corresponding lines for a regular $n$-gon are:

$$\begin{cases}
x \cos \tfrac{(p+q)\pi}{2n} + y \sin \tfrac{(p+q)\pi}{2n} + \cos \tfrac{(p-q)\pi}{2n} &=&0\\
x \cos \tfrac{(r+s)\pi}{2n} + y \sin \tfrac{(r+s)\pi}{2n} + \cos \tfrac{(r-s)\pi}{2n} &=&0\\
x \cos \tfrac{(u+v)\pi}{2n} + y \sin \tfrac{(u+v)\pi}{2n}+ \cos \tfrac{(u-v)\pi}{2n} &=&0
\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

(think indeed that for example, in isoceles triangle $M_pOM_q$, where $O$ is the center of the circle, the altitude $OH$ issued from $O$, normal to line $M_pM_q$ has the same direction as the angle bissector of angle $M_pOM_q$ and this bissector has polar angle $\tfrac{(p+q)\pi}{2n}$ ; besides, distance $OH = \cos \tfrac{(p-q)\pi}{2n}$.

In the discussion of a system like (3), the only way it can have a solution is by being redundant which is equivalent to having its main determinant equal to $0$. Therefore, here is a necessary and sufficient condition of intersection of the 3 diagonals :

$$\det \pmatrix{
\cos \tfrac{(p+q)\pi}{2n}&\sin \tfrac{(p+q)\pi}{2n}& \cos \tfrac{(p-q)\pi}{2n}\\
\cos \tfrac{(r+s)\pi}{2n}&\sin \tfrac{(r+s)\pi}{2n}& \cos \tfrac{(r-s)\pi}{2n}\\
\cos \tfrac{(u+v)\pi}{2n}&\sin \tfrac{(u+v)\pi}{2n}& \cos \tfrac{(u-v)\pi}{2n}
}=0 \tag{4}$$

Remark: Let $C$ be the common point of these 3 diagonals. Condition (4) allows $C$ outside the polygon. These cases can be cancelled by obtaining the coordinates of $C$ using an element of the kernel $(a,b,c)^T$ of the previous matrix : if $c \ne 0$, the common point is $(a/c,b/c)$ ; otherwise, if $c=0$, it means that $C$ is at infinity, i.e., the diagonals are all parallel.

Condition (4) can be given a complex version by setting $\alpha:=e^{i \pi/n}$ as follows.

$$\det \pmatrix{
\alpha^{(p+q)}&\alpha^{-(p+q)}&(\alpha^{(p-q)}+\alpha^{-(p-q)})\\
\alpha^{(r+s)}&\alpha^{-(r+s)}&(\alpha^{(r-s)}+\alpha^{-(r-s)})\\
\alpha^{(u+v)}&\alpha^{-(u+v)}&(\alpha^{(u-v)}+\alpha^{-(u-v)})\\
}=0$$

Remark: Condition (4) on the nullity of the determinant could have been obtained in a different way : indeed, there is formula for the area of the triangle knowing the equations of its sides that can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/901819/305862) with a proof by ... Blue, involving the square of the determinant we have used. It is therefore equivalent to express that the area is $0$ and that the three chords concur.

Comment: A similar idea (using a 36-gon) can be found [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2905980/305862)

Comment: Thoughts ... Defining $\pi_n:=\pi/n$, let chords $A_0A_1$, $B_0B_1$, $C_0C_1$ have endpoints $A_k=(\cos(2a_k\pi_n),\sin(2a_k\pi_n))$, etc. It's straightforward to show that the chords concur when $$\sum_{cyc} \cos((a_0-a_1)\pi_n)\;\sin(((b_0+b_1)-(c_0+c_1))\pi_n)=0$$ Alternatively, treating each endpoint as a complex number, we can write $$\sum_{cyc} A_0 A_1 ((B_0 + B_1)-(C_0+C_1))=0$$ (Not that either of these makes *finding* concurrencies particularly easy.) Your examples correspond to $n=36$, with $$(a_0,a_1;b_0,b_1;c_0,c_1)=(0,19;15,23;20,7)\;\text{and}\;(0,23;7,26;15,29)$$

Comment: @Blue Thank you very very much, once again. Please transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: [Adventitious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley's_Adventitious_Angles) is still the word...

Answer (score 1):

Converting a comment to an answer, as requested ...

---

Defining $\pi_n := \pi/n$, let chords $A_0 A_1$, $B_0 B_1$, $C_0 C_1$ have endpoints
$$A_k := \left(\,\cos(2a_k\pi_n), \sin(2a_k\pi_n)\,\right), \;\text{etc}$$
It's straightforward (with assistance from a computer algebra system) to show that the chords (or, possibly, *extensions* thereof) concur when
$$\sum_{cyc}\cos((a_0-a_1)\pi_n)\,\sin\left(\,((b_0+b_1)-(c_0+c_1))\pi_n\,\right) = 0 \tag1$$
Alternatively, taking the endpoints as complex numbers (namely, appropriate powers of the $n$-th root of unity), we have
$$\sum_{cyc} A_0 A_1\left((B_0+B_1)-(C_0+C_1)\right) = 0 \tag2$$
(Not that either of these makes *finding* concurrencies particularly easy.)

OP's examples correspond to $n=36$, with
$$(a_0,a_1;b_0,b_1;c_0,c_1)\;=\;(0,19;15,23;20,7)\;\;\text{and}\;\;(0,23;7,26;15,29)$$

Comment: Please, see the Edit I just wrote. Thank you again.

Comment: In fact, after having written it,  I realized that one could write the solution in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer.**

About **Question 1**, concurrence in $D$ of the $36$-gon diagonals can be showed resorting back to angle chasing.

In fact, e.g., $EID$ is a $30-75-75$ isosceles triangle, and therefore the bisector of $\angle IED$, that is $EJ$, perpendiculary bisects $ID$. This means in turn that $IJD$ is isosceles, and, since $\measuredangle JID = 50^\circ$, we have that $\measuredangle EJD = 40^\circ$, which proves the alignment.

[image]

Comment: One can also see that $IE=EB$, $BA=AK$, and $KJ=JI$, hence $KE$, $IA$, and $BJ$ are the bisectors of the angles of the triangle $KIB$, so they intersect at the incenter of $KIB$. Alternatively, one can see that $AI\perp EJ$, $AJ\perp KE$, and $AE\perp JB$ so $AI$, $EK$, and $JB$ are the altitudes of $AEJ$, hence they concur at the orthocenter of $AEJ$.

Comment: @timon92 yes!! As a matter of fact, I was also looking for bisectors, to prove concurrence in $C$, but did not manage to find all the necessary information. Thanks!